# Unity IOC, can't fix the parameterless constructor issue

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, unity-container

I have the following constructor (only one for the controller):

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager,
        IAccountService accountSrv)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
        AccountService = accountSrv;
    }

    private IAccountService AccountService { get; }

    private ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager { get; }

    private ApplicationUserManager UserManager { get; }
```

And I'd like MVC to call it with proper parameters, so I tried this:

Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        DALMapper.Mapping();
        LabMapper.Mapping();

        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container
            .RegisterType<IDALContext, DALContext>()
            .RegisterType<IConsultantService, ConsultantService>()
            .RegisterType<IProjectService, ProjectService>()
            .RegisterType<IAccountService, AccountService>()
            .RegisterType<AccountController, AccountController>()
            .RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUserManager>()
            .RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager, ApplicationSignInManager>()
            .RegisterInstance<IAccountService>(new AccountService(new DALContext()), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
        ;

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

(UnityDependencyResolver being:)

```
public class UnityDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public UnityDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return _container.Resolve(serviceType);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
        }
        catch
        {
            return new List<object>();
        }
    }
}
```

Where I register every types needed (the result feel weird though when in/from types are the same (I'm that new to Unity)).

But it doesn't work. (As far as I know, since MV3, the default controller factory will use the service locator, so one doesn't need to implement it's own factory).

What's wrong?

Current result:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging it up more (downloaded the Unity source code, built it, added a reference to the dll, added the pdb to the symbols locations (debug))*, I could see the error was coming from another constructor which requirs parameters.

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }
```

(I've yet to solve this, but that should be easy).

*is there an easier way to step into a third party library's code? Let me know in the comment.

Comment: Unity is published on symbolsource.org: http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/Unity.  So you should be able to debug using it as a symbol server: http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Wiki/Using.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, there's a problem resolving the dependencies for ApplicationUserManager  and ApplicationSignInManager. 
This is the code that solved the problem for me:

```
//for accountcontroller
        container.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDBContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(new InjectionFactory(o => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));
```

Comment: Finding more and more of these chestnuts. Another I had to add was container.RegisterType<IIdentity>(new InjectionFactory(u => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity)); in order to use User.Identity in any of my controllers as normal.